# assign values based on a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list1  with names:

```
   ["SAM","TOM","LOUIS"]
```

And I have a dict1 like this (where in the list of values there are no repeated names:

```
{"NICE": ["SAM", "MAIK", "CARL", "LAURA", "MARTH"],
 "BAD": ["LOUIS", "TOM", "KEVIN"],
 "GOOD": ["BILL", "JEN", "ALEX"]}
```

How could I iterate throught the list1 so that if any of the names appear in any of the lists of the dict1 it assigns the corresponding key of the dict?

I am looking forward to generate the following output:

```
["NICE","BAD","BAD"]
```

which would correspond to the keys of the values that appear in the list : SAM, TOM , LOUIS .

This is what I thought about:

```
lista=[]
for k,v in dict1:
    for values in arr1:
        if values in v:
            lista.append(v)
lista
```

However not sure how to iterate over the different `v`,  how can I get the desired output in an efficient manner?

Comment: Your dict is the exact opposite of what you really need here.  If it was something like `{'SAM': 'NICE, 'MAIK', 'NICE', ...` you could simply do `[dict1[name] for name in arr1]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an intermediate dict that maps names to their keys in `dict1`:

```
categories = {name: category for category, names in dict1.items() for name in names}
```

so that you can map the names in `list1` to their respective keys efficiently with:

```
[categories[name] for name in list1]
```

which returns:

```
['NICE', 'BAD', 'BAD']
```

Comment: Simple and beautiful. I forgot you can make a nested loop in a comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need the `items()` function for dictionaries here. For each name, iterate over all of the dictionary pairs and stop when a match is found, adding the corresponding adjective to your list.

```
lista = []
for name in list1:
    for adjective, names in dict1.items():
        if name in names:
            lista.append(adjective)
            break
return lista
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to achieve your result.

The way you intended was to use dict1.items(). Unfortunately, that way is computationally slow, so for the sake of completeness I'll add the the more efficient way:

```
# First, convert the dict to a different representation:
from itertools import chain, repeat

# Change {k: [v1,v2], k2: [v3,v4]} to {v1: k, v2: k, v3: k2, v4: k2}
name_to_adjective = dict(chain.from_iterable(zip(v, repeat(k)) for k, v in a.items()))
```

Name_to_adjective is now equal to this:

```
{'ALEX': 'GOOD',
 'BILL': 'GOOD',
 'CARL': 'NICE',
 'JEN': 'GOOD',
 'KEVIN': 'BAD',
 'LAURA': 'NICE',
 'LOUIS': 'BAD',
 'MAIK': 'NICE',
 'MARTH': 'NICE',
 'SAM': 'NICE',
 'TOM': 'BAD'}
```

Then, you can get your result in one run:

```
result = [name_to_adjective[name] for name in list1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will give you your desired output:

```
    L = ["SAM","TOM","LOUIS"]
    D = {"NICE": ["SAM", "MAIK", "CARL", "LAURA", "MARTH"]
    , "BAD": ["LOUIS", "TOM", "KEVIN"]
    , "GOOD": ["BILL", "JEN", "ALEX"]}

    lista = []
    for key in D.keys():
        for name in L:
            if name in D[key]:
                lista.append(key)
    print(lista)
```

The *D.keys()* part gives you a list of the keys in a friendly manner (e.g, **["NICE", "BAD", "GOOD"]**).

You iterate over this and then look for each name from L (in order) in the dictionary.

This is not the most efficient way to do this, however, it's a more straightforward approach.